# Possible Proof by Induction/Very Basic While Loop

Tags: induction, computer-science, programming

I feel it is a math induction proof. I tried to draw a [picture](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://cdn.programiz.com/sites/tutorial2program/files/c-while-loop.jpg&imgrefurl=https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-do-while-loops&h=411&w=300&tbnid=to4lMUTdhP5SnM:&q=while%20loop%20programming&tbnh=160&tbnw=116&usg=AFrqEzfLufd079W64F7BPH0mPdFcPrUYUw&vet=12ahUKEwjxiMSBpa_dAhWOrFkKHa0mBxAQ9QEwAHoECAUQBg..i&docid=KN82WJd2JqWuVM&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxiMSBpa_dAhWOrFkKHa0mBxAQ9QEwAHoECAUQBg) to try to help with the inductive step but was unsuccessful (I only got the base case). I am sure there is a technique to prove loops like this.

> $\textbf{Question}:$ How do I prove the following proposition below?

Proposition: Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $f(n)=n$ where $f(n)$ is given by the below diagram.
[image]

Proof: Base case: $n=1$. Then, $0<1$ is true which means $i\leftarrow 0+1=1$. Repeating the loop, we know $\underbrace{i}_{1}<1$ is false. Thus, $i$ must be $1$ when the loop is complete. Hence, $f(1)=1$ which proves the base case.

Comment: Your loop invariant is $i \leq n$.

Comment: I keep seeing that term used looking stuff like this up. What is the loop invariant?  How can that be used to prove this result?

Comment: Is there a mathematical way to go about it without going into too much detail about what the loop invariant is?

Comment: A loop invariant is a formula in the program variables that is true before the loop executes. ($0 \leq n$ holds no matter what natural number you choose for $n$.)  If the loop invariant and the loop condition ($i < n$) hold, then the loop invariant still holds after one iteration.  Finally, when the loop terminates, the loop invariant still holds, but the loop condition no longer does: from $i \leq n \wedge \neg(i < n)$ one infers $i=n$.

Comment: So is this not an inductive proof? I just thought it was an inductive proof. It might not be though.

Comment: It is an inductive proof.  The loop invariant is your inductive claim.  When you prove that it holds before the loop starts, you are proving the base case.  When you prove that it is preserved by one iteration of the loop, you prove the inductive step.  Finally, your inductive claim must be strong enough to let you prove your theorem, which in this case is the postcondition of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We claim that $i = n$ after execution of the while loop.  To prove this claim we make the auxiliary claim that $i \leq n$ is a loop invariant.  That is, that $i \leq n$ holds on entry to the loop, and that it is maintained by each iteration of the loop.

When the loop terminates, we know that the loop condition is no longer true, that is, that $i \geq n$.  Since $i \leq n$ is still true, we obtain $i=n$.  Now for the details.  The proof is an induction on the number of iterations of the loop.  Since this style of reasoning is common when proving properties of programs, the fact that we are dealing with induction is often given for granted.  To bring the connection to the fore, let's define $P_k$ as "$i \leq n$ after $k$ iterations of the loop."

---

After the assignment $i \leftarrow 0$, $i \leq n$ holds because no natural number is less than $0$.  That is, our invariant holds when $0$ iterations of the loop have been completed.  This proves the base case of the induction; that is, it establishes $P_0$.

Suppose that after $k$ iterations the loop is still running (that is, $i < n$) and $P_k$ holds ($i \leq n$).  In this simple case, $i < n$ implies $i \leq n$; hence we can focus on what we can infer about the state of the program after $k+1$ iterations from $i<n$ being true after $k$ iterations.

Let's denote by $i_{k+1}$ the value of $i$ at the end of iteration $k+1$ and by $i_k$ the value of $i$ after $k$ iterations.  (That is, at the beginning of iteration $k+1$.)  The effect of the assignment $i \leftarrow i+1$ is to establish $i_{k+1} = i_k + 1$.  Now, from $i_k < n$ follows immediately that $i_{k+1} \leq n$.  With this we have proved that $i \leq n$ is a loop invariant of the program, which holds after iteration $k+1$ if it holds after iteration $k$; in particular, it holds at the end of the the last iteration of the loop.  As mentioned above, this implies both $i \leq n$ and $i \not< n$, or $i = n$.  Another way to put it is that $P_k$ is inductive.

---

Looking at a simple case like this it is easy to overlook the fact that termination of a loop is not a given.  In general, one has to prove that the loop terminates to be able to say that "when the loop terminates, the invariant still holds."  This is usually done by identifying an integer-valued function of the program state that decreases at each iteration and is bounded from below.  If such a *ranking function* exists, then the number of iterations is necessarily bounded.  For our loop, $n-i$ will do.

---

Two aspects of the proof deserve attention. One is the claim of the effect of the assignment $i \leftarrow i+1$.  When reasoning about programs one chooses axioms that describe the effect of program statements on the program's state so that they reflect what programs actually do.  So, the effect of the assignment, as far as the proof is concerned, is simply the application of the axiom governing assignments. Here I have (somewhat informally) followed the popular axiomatization due to Tony Hoare.

The second aspect worthy of note is how one comes up with loop invariants and ranking functions.  There is no algorithm that will compute either.  In practice people (and programs that reason about other programs) use heuristics.

Comment: I hope you realize that I will be giving you this answer as this answer is beyond extremely helpful and very much appreciated. Could you please elaborate on the ranking function, termination part as to how you would do it here?  I understand from your point of view that termination here may seem obvious, but I would very much so like the details as to the general proof for the termination part. How does $n-i$ come into play? Thank you for your help!

Comment: On second thought, I think I can take it from here. What a thorough answer!!!! Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm glad you find my answer useful.  If I may recommend a next step, write a simple function that  with a loop that finds the maximum value in an array of numbers, and prove that it is indeed correct; that is, that it terminates and, that it returns the desired value.  You'll be using $i \leq n$ again, but also the claim that after $k$ iterations, your function has found the maximum value among the first $k$ elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you found f(1)=1 is true

Now, consider the proposition is true for n=k. that is f(k) = k

Now we need to prove the proposition is true for n=k+1.

i=0, n=k+1

after k iterations, i=k

now for (k+1)th iteration i=k+1=n and hence the loop stops.

therefore f(k+1) = k+1

therefore, by principle of mathematical Induction, we prove the result. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

(*Too long for a comment*.)   The crux of the inductive step is that...

```
i ← 0
while i < n+1
   i ← i+1
```

...is equivalent to:

```
i ← 0          |
while i < n    |
   i ← i+1     |  <---  i = f(n) = n once the loop completes, by the induction hypothesis

i ← i+1           <---  i = f(n)+1 = n+1, which proves the induction step f(n+1) = n+1
```

This is more of a programming question, rather than a math one. For a formal math proof, you would need to first formally define what the terms mean, from `←` assignment to `while` loops.